# Jquery FIle Upload Multiple images: Grouping files together

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

Trying to use [jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to push multiple images belonging to different albums from a single page. The idea is to create multiple albums at once, and the images chosen could have images belonging to one or many albums.

for eg: say of the total 10 images, 3 belong to album #1, 4 for album #2 and so on...

I am thinking of providing the ability to drag and drop the images, say if the images 1, 3 and 7 belong to the same album, user could drag and drop, images 3 and 7 on 1, and the UI would group them together giving the impression they belong to same album and they will share other custom input (album name, description etc)

I am not sure if there is  a way to group images together so that the server knows that a set of images belong to a specific album.

Has anyone done anything similar, any ideas? pointers?

Note 1: Edited for implementation clarity.

Comment: How would the user specify which album the images belongs to?

Comment: I am thinking of providing the ability to drag and drop the images, say if the images 1, 3 and 7 belong to the same album, user could drag and drop, images 3 and 7 on 1, and the UI would group them together giving the impression they belong to same album.